# Fade in Fade out between page html and change image with array script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, arrays

I have a small problem. I can do a fadout fadin on an entire page by clicking html links. But I want to change the images that correspond with my links in array.

Below my code to fadeIn and fadeOut between pages html:

Script

```
$(window).load(function(){

$("#overlay").fadeOut(1500);
$("a.transition").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

   linkLocation = this.href;
  $("#overlay").fadeIn(1000, function() {
window.location = linkLocation;

  return false;
    });
});
});
```

Css

```
#overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  background: #fcc916 url(img/logo/blablabla.png) no-repeat center center;
  /*background: #ffffff;*/
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 314159;
}
```

html

```
<div id="overlay"></div>
```

I know I have to do a array with images and retrieve them in getElementByld but I do not know how ...

Thanks for your precious help and sorry for my english

Comment: If we can see your attempts to use this array we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try ...

```
$("#overlay")
    .attr("style", "background: #fcc916 url(img/logo/" + fromarray[i] + ".png) no-repeat center center");
```

... this will change the background image via jQuery.  the .png portion could be coming from the array, as well.

Comment: Didn't you forget the `background` part of the attribute?

Comment: This is a good solution! Thanks rfornal. So I think have to do a href array to link the images for each link href html ...?

Comment: you could do something very similar ... `.attr("href", "images/" + name[i]);`